# How to set initialization order for a properties object?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

Ex: suppose I have

```
    private double foo;
    private double bar;

    public double foo
    {
        get { return foo; }
        set
        {
            foo = value;
        }
    }

    public double bar
    {
        get { return bar; }
        set
        {
            
            bar = value * foo ;
        }
    }
```

When this object is initialized I want to set the order in that someone first sets a value to foo, then sets a value to bar. I know that I can throw an exception if foo is not initialized within bar but is there a way to set this requirement so whoever instantiates this properties object this will not have any issues to begin with?

Comment: I would think that you should define Foo and Bar, and then have a calculated property FooBar. Then it doesn't matter if you set Foo or Bar first.

Comment: Or accept both in the constructor, unless you really need them to be able to be mutated through the lifetime of the object.

Comment: If inside `public double bar` you do `get { return bar; }` you will get at runtime an `StackOverflowException` when accesing the property. You should rename your private variables.

Comment: @Cleptus: It won't get as far as an exception - the code won't compile due to declaring multiple members with the same name.

Comment: As an aside, it's pretty odd for `x.bar = x.bar;` to be anything other than a no-op. (In this case, if foo is 5, then each time you execute that "usually no-op" statement, the value will grow by a factor of 5...)

Comment: To strictly answer your question, I would write a unique constructor such as "New MyObject(double foo)". But, your "bar" property is not right. If I write "yourObject.bar = 5", I expect that "bar" is now equal to 5, not to 5 * foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that public setter are not appropriate in this particular case. I would suggest using a constructor instead:

```
public MyClass(double foo, double value) => (Foo, Bar) = (foo, value*foo);
public double Foo {get; private set;}
public double Bar {get; private set;}
```

Note that I did not call the parameter `bar`, since that would lead to the expectation that the `Bar`-property should have the value of the `bar` parameter.

You might opt to give Bar a default value if you wish. But in general, the constructor should ensure that the type is fully constructed, so any required properties should be injected as constructor parameters.

I would in general not expect that a setter has any complex behavior. Common logic would be things like range checking or to update things that depend on the property. If you need some more complex logic you could add it as a method, this give a hint that the method does more than just setting a property:

```
public void SetBar(double value) => Bar = value * foo;
```

Or use a separate property that calculates `foo*bar`:

```
public MyClass(double foo, double bar) => (Foo, Bar) = (foo, bar);
public double Foo {get; set;}
public double Bar {get; set;}
public double FooBar => Foo * Bar;
```

This would by far be my preferred solution since it would be very difficult to get this kind of code wrong. It should be perfectly obvious what all properties does.